# fopen() fails . Is it the server?

Tags: php, fopen

I have a problem with fopen() function inside a bigger script so i extracted a simple routine that opens a file i use this :

```
<?php

    $fh = fopen("users.txt","r");

    if ($fh)
    {
        echo "File opened";
    }
    else echo "Unable to open file";

?>
```

The file exists is in the same path such as the php file but the server displays the following page:

> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@....com and inform
>   them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done
>   that may have caused the error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
>   log.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to
>   use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

What could be the source of this problem ?

Comment: The file permissions are 777 so i don't think it is a problem

Comment: Check your server logs (usually in `/var/logs/apache2`)

Comment: and is the file in the current working directory - getcwd()

Comment: I checked i got this : "[Wed Jan 04 08:53:12 2012] [error] [client 79.xx.xx.xx] SoftException in Application.cpp:264: File "/home/add_device.php" is writeable by others"

Comment: It's hard to tell what triggers a premature shutdown of the script with the code you have provided. It sounds like you have a fatal error somewhere in the code, you need to debug the script to find out where.

Comment: @hakre the code i posted gives the error what can i debug at 3 lines of code ?

Comment: Does any other PHP code execute properly? Because this message usually really does mean an error in configuration.

Comment: > The file permissions are 777 so i don't think it is a problem 
>  File "/home/add_device.php" is writeable by others"
Ironically, it is. Set them to 755.

Comment: @asaddude yes i have installed a phpbb on the hosting and works fine

Comment: downvote and closing reason please.

Comment: @opc0de: I didn't downvote. The closing reason(s) are visible if you press the *close (2)* link. Also notice that your issue is related to server configuration - which is not part of your question. Additionally, you have not provided distinct error information which leads to guessing by those who want to answer.

Comment: The people that voted to close the question are stupid. Now that 'A Sad Dude' has found the reason they can see that the question is not localized.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The file permissions are 777 so i don't think it is a problem

Ironically, it is.

> File "/home/add_device.php" is writeable by others"

Set them to 755.

Comment: Still the same error. Is the path correct ?? do i need to set another path ?

Comment: Good answer. The error message seems triggered by [suPHP](http://www.suphp.org/Home.html).

Comment: [Wed Jan 04 10:46:19 2012] [error] [client 79.117.216.153] File does not exist: /home/500.shtml